# Codeigniter pagination for list of data

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Can I make a pagination of a list in Codeigniter?
I have tried to make pagination of a list instead of a table, but still not working.

this is my View.php:

```
<ul>
<?php   if(count($usernamelist) > 0)
    {?>
        <li><?php echo $usernamelist ?></li>
<?php   }   ?>
</ul>
<?php echo links ?>
```

and this my Controller.php for the pagination:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."abouthistory/index";
$config['total_rows'] = 15;
$config['per_page'] = 6;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Is there any way to configure my list to be segmented into a pagination?

Comment: how do you alocate `$usernamelist`?

Answer (score 0):

"still not working" is the most useless comment anyone can make when asking for help.

Pagination is a way of controlling what data comes from your database, and giving you navigation elements to request it. The results you get back can be displayed any way you like.

You haven't included where you are getting $usernamelist from, but I'm assuming this is a result set or array, so you'll need to foreach it, not echo the array.